# Clipped button doesn't receive touch input

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button

I have a FAB that resides in between two layouts. Using negative margin alongside with `android:clipChildren` and `android:clipToPadding` both set to false I'm able to produce this pleasantly placed little button:

[image]

Now, the problem is that the bottom half of the FAB isn't receiving touch input or in other word: not clickable. I've tried playing around with `android:elevation` making sure that it sits in the highest Z-value possible but the problem remains. The top-half, meanwhile, is working just fine.

[image]

I'm kinda stuck on this, could anyone here help me on what to do? Below is my `XML` for the layout, in case you need it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rl_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <id.ridsatrio.taggr.widgets.ObservableScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sv_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <id.ridsatrio.taggr.widgets.SquaredImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_details_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="Album Art Image"
                android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_none"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/def_album_art" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/v_anchor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/details_header_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_details_header"
                android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_low" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_track_fields"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/v_anchor"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                ...

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/v_divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/details_section_divider_height"
                android:layout_below="@id/ll_track_fields"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/details_section_divider_margin_start"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/item_horizontal_margin_xlarge"
                android:background="@color/dividers_light" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_album_fields"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/v_divider"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                ...

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/details_header_height"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_low">

                ...

                <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab_details"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/details_header_fab_margin_bottom"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/details_header_fab_margin_start"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_medium"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_down"
                    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/primary_dark"
                    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary"
                    fab:fab_type="mini" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </id.ridsatrio.taggr.widgets.ObservableScrollView>

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Should you need more details on this, I would also glad to provide more.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit**: Thanks to **MoshErsan**, I finally able to get this working. Here's my working `XML` in case anyone encounter the same problem as mine:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rl_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <id.ridsatrio.taggr.widgets.ObservableScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sv_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <id.ridsatrio.taggr.widgets.SquaredImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_details_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="Album Art Image"
                android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_none"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/def_album_art" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/v_anchor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/details_header_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_details_header"
                android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_low" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_track_fields"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/v_anchor"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                ...

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/v_divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/details_section_divider_height"
                android:layout_below="@id/ll_track_fields"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/details_section_divider_margin_start"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/item_horizontal_margin_xlarge"
                android:background="@color/dividers_light" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_album_fields"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/v_divider"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                ...

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/details_header_height"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_low">

                ...

            </RelativeLayout>

            <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_details"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rl_header"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_header"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/details_header_fab_margin_bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/details_header_fab_margin_start"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_medium"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_down"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/primary_dark"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary"
                fab:fab_type="mini" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </id.ridsatrio.taggr.widgets.ObservableScrollView>

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

If there's a thing to learn from here it's this: **Setting `android:clipChilden` to `false` will allow said View to draw outside it's parent layout BUT any touch input would still be restricted to the parent's boundaries.**

Comment: can you move the FAB to be latest view in the root layout?? I mean increase its Z index

Comment: @MoshErsan, doesn't that means extra work for positioning?

Comment: I think the problem is that even you did bring the FAB into front of the layout next to it, still the layout consumes the touch event, so I still recommend to use FrameLayout as root layout and put the FAB as last view in it

Comment: and to understand why it doesn't receive touch events in the bottom part of FAB, that because you did use `                android:clipChildren="false"` so actually the parent bounders is smaller than that but the draw happens out side it, so when the touch event is received to the parent first then it tries to divert it to the desired child, and the touch event must be within parent bounders, so the bottom part of FAB is outside the bounders of the parent, and the touch event is not for him

Comment: @MoshErsan, I see.. So what should I do then? Is putting the FAB as a sibling of the `@+id/rl_header` (still a child of the `ObservableScrollView`) enough or should I move it all the way to the root as a child of `@+id/rl_root`?

Comment: @MoshErsan, you, sir, are a GENIUS. I moved my FAB to be a sibling of `@+id/rl_header` **and it worked!** Now, please post an answer to this so that I could accept it and give the reputation you deserve. Once again, thank you!

Comment: can you edit your question and post the new working xml? so the others know what happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move your `FAB` Z index in the layout to be on the top of the other `views` in the screen, so when the touch event occurs the `FAB` should receive the touch event before another views.

and to understand why it doesn't receive touch events in the bottom part of FAB, that because you did use `android:clipChildren="false"` so actually the parent bounders is smaller than that but the draw happens out side it, so when the touch event is received to the parent first then it tries to divert it to the desired child, and the touch event must be within parent bounders, so the bottom part of FAB is outside the bounders of the parent, and the touch event is not for him.